# How to decide which method to call according to user input?

Tags: java

I have a sorting basic problem:

> Write a program called Sort that will take a sorting order followed by a list of numbers from the commandline and print out the sorted list of numbers

for example : `java Sort asc 12 2 3 -9 8`

and output is

> -9 2 3 8 12

and the opposite if I write "desc" and the numbers.

My problem is: how do I tell my program to which function should it go?
I only know how to send it to each function, but not to one of them.

I don't have problem with the sorting just telling the program which function to do.

Comment: `if(args[0].equals("asc")) { ... }`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say you can call each function but not one, how can that be harder? Please include the code you have in your question so we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For telling your program to which function should it go you can use if else statement, the function will act according to the argument "asc" or "desc":

```
if(args[0].equals("asc")) {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: by convention, constants should be placed on left side `if("asc".equals(args[0]))`

Comment: @rkosegi, that's [debatable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/doesnt-if-0-value-do-more-harm-than-good).

Comment: @jaco0646 : what's debatable on avoiding NPE if args[0] == null ?